# How to print the names of the rendered XHTML files

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jboss, jboss7.x, filenames

My problem is very simple, but I cannot find a way of solving it. I have a lot of JSF XHTML pages (IceFaces library used, but I suppose this does not change anything), some of them including other pages with a `ui:include` directive. This can be of course recursive, and when a bug can be reproduced on the application, it is not always easy to find which XHTML displayed it.

What I want to do is the following : print the name of **all the XHTML pages** used during the rendering of the web page. The only way I could find up to now is add a display in each of my XHTML files. For example, the `displayCustomer.xhtml` would have this as a first line :

```
<outputText rendered="#{myBean.debugXHTML}" value="displayCustomer.xhtml" />
```

This works but suppose I should add to all of my files a similar instruction. If possible, I'd like to have it without changing anything to my XHTML files. If this is not possible, I'd like to have it with an output text which is exactly the same for all my files (so a small shell script can add this line right after the `ui:composition` directive).

I'm using the mojarra 2.1.X version on a JBoss 7.1.X (don't know if this can help).

Thanks in advance for your help, I cannot figure out any solution.

Comment: Edit your question keeping 'politeness' in mind so that we won't be distracted from reading. We understand that you could be exhausted but that emphasis shouldn't be put on us.

Comment: That was not supposed to be rude, edited !

Comment: Thanks. But I understand what you must have felt! For now you have two answers, depending on what you want to output: view I'd, or request URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution...

**Add this in your xhtml page :**

```
<ice:outputText id="myHiddenCompo" rendered="#{DebugXHTML}" value="#{bean.getFileNameAndPath()}"  />
```

**Create in the BackingBean a method like this one:**

```
  public final String getFileNameAndPath(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
    UIComponent c = JSFHelper.findComponent(root, "myHiddenCompo");
    return c.getValueExpression("value").toString();
  }
```

**JSFHelper.java extract :**

```
public static UIComponent findComponent(final UIComponent c, final String id) {
    if (id.equals(c.getId())) {
        return c;
    }

    Iterator<UIComponent> kids = c.getFacetsAndChildren();
    while (kids.hasNext()) {
        UIComponent found = findComponent(kids.next(), id);
        if (found != null) {
            return found;
        }
     }
 return null;
}
```

**Result:**

> /WEB-INF/includes/folder/verticalTabs/folderDisplay.xhtml @8,114
>   value="#{#{bean.getFileNameAndPath()}}"

*After that you can use substring to get the part you need.*

**I've found a 'better' implementation, because above, we have a problem with multiple id's (jsf 2 find duplicate id's)**

**Just add this line in xhtml:**

```
 <ice:outputText rendered="#{DebugXHTML}" value="#{bean.getFileNameAndPath(component)} "/>
```

***component** is a keyword of jsf 2 that represent the current component.*

**And modify backing bean code :**

```
  public final String getFileNameAndPath(UIComponent hiddenCompo) {
    String manipString = hiddenCompo.getValueExpression("value").toString();
    return manipString.substring(0, manipString.indexOf(".xhtml") + 6);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`#{view.viewId}` will get you the name of the current view being rendered. So you'll have

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{myBean.debugXHTML}" value="#{view.viewId}" />
```

The `view` object is an implicit EL object that is analogous to the `UIViewRoot` object you'd pull from `FacesContext` in the backing bean.

Comment: This solution does output the browser URL : `/pages/index.xhtml`. That is not the output I'm looking for. I'd like `displayCustomer.xhtml` to be printed (`index.xhtml` does include the other files).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to using `#{view.viewId}`, you can also make use of anther implicit EL object, `#{request}`, that gives you access to [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) instance, so that you could get not the view id in form `/index.html`, but the URL in the browser via, for example,

```
#{request.requestURL}?#{request.queryString}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. It displays `http://localhost:8080/##CONTEXT_ROOT##/pages/index.jsf`, close to the first solution proposed in this topic. I'd like to have the `displayCustomer.xhtml` as output, which is the name of the file included in the main page, not the main page itself.

Comment: State clearly what you want to output. Why do you expect it to output something different from what you see in the browser bar?

Comment: My english is not perfect, I did think my main post was clear, but apparently not entirely. The adress in the browser is ALWAYS `/pages/index.jsf` and nothing else. Everything is included with a `ui:include` composition. What I want to know is which _included XHTML page_ did the rendering. For example, I'd like a `mainMenu.xhtml` text next to the main menu of the application, a `subMenu.xhtml` text next to the sub menu, a `displayCustomer.xhtml` text in the center of the page if I am browsing the page displaying the customer details, ...